# onPurchasesUpdated callback was not called in the case of "Slow test card" in Android In-App billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am developing an `Android` app with `In-App` Billing feature.

I didn't use the `AIDL`, but use latest librrary:

```
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'
```

Google has providing 4 test card options.

```
1. Slow test card, approves after a few minutes
2. Test card, always approves
3. Test card, always declines
4. Slow test card, declines after a few minutes
```

When I test using my test account, 1, 2, 3 test card options worked fine in my App.

But only 4 didn't work...

```
I think it similar to case 1.
The only difference is "approve or decline"
```

In the case of #1, "`onPurchasesUpdated()`" callback method was called after 1 min.

So I can handle the `"slow environment".`

But in the case of #4, `"onPurchasesUpdated()"` callback method was not called after 1 min.

How can I handle this?

My app requires charge some coin using the `In-App` billing.

So I should call `"consume"` method after charging the coins.

But in the case of #4, there are no responses.

So I couldn't call consume...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my app. Well, I get a _on_purchases_updated() signal but you have to acknowledge the purchase.

In the cases #1 and #4 I receive a _on_purchase_acknowledgement_error() signal immediately.
In case #1 I receive a _on_purchase_acknowledged() signal a few minutes later and I can confirm the purchase.
But in #4 I never receive another signal from Play Store, not even one _on_purchase_acknowledgement_error() signal.

So I created a TimeOut timer to manage this. It starts whe I receive the first _on_purchase_acknowledgement_error() signal. And after a few minutes discards the purchase if you dont receive a  _on_purchase_acknowledged() signal.

P.S. I'm using Godot Game Engine but this depends of Play Store so I guess will be the same with you.